# If any two sequences converge to the same limit, prove they are concurrent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

The sequences $\{x_n \},\{y_n \}$ are called concurrent if and only if $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. We denote this property as $\{x_n \} \approx \{y_n \}$. Prove if any two sequences converge to the same limit, they are concurrent.

I was thinking something like for any $\epsilon \gt 0, d(x,y)  \lt \epsilon$, right? Since the two sequences converge to the same point, you know that for an $\epsilon \gt 0$ you will have $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that after those two indices, the sequences will be $\epsilon$-close to the limit point. Now take the max of the two, i.e. $\max(N_1,N_2)$. Then apply triangle inequality. Is this method correct ? Is there any other way to prove this question ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: I have modified my question.

Comment: Start with $d(x_n,y_n) \leq d(x_n,x)+d(x,y_n)$ and the apply your argument. [$x$ is the common limit ].